# Php to json not working

Tags: php, json

Trying to make json file from this php but its not working what im missing

```
 // Initialize variable for database credentials
 $dbhost = 'localhost';
 $dbuser = 'root';
 $dbpass = '';
 $dbname = 'users';

 $dblink = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
 if ($dblink->connect_errno) {
 printf("Failed to connect to database");
 exit();
 }

 //Fetch 3 rows from actor table
 $result = $dblink->query("SELECT * FROM profile");

 //Initialize array variable
 $dbdata = array();

 //Fetch into associative array
 while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc())  {
 $dbdata[]=$row;
 }

 //Print array in JSON format
 echo json_encode($dbdata);
```

Comment: Have you checked your error logs? You're making an assumption the query is working.
Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: Try echoing array also. Just to check you are creating a proper array.

Comment: What is the actual result you're seeing? Do you get an empty array or a blank response?

Comment: yea it was a utf8 problem coming from the mysql database    solved whit this code mysqli_set_charset($dblink,"utf8");

Comment: You can answer your own question.

Comment: You might get a better idea if you add `echo json_last_error();` at the bottom of you script  - it might give you a better idea of what is wrong.  Check out the manual for possible error codes http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php